# delete account with facebook credential

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to delete a firebase account thas is only linked to a facebook credential but I always get the error ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN, even if before to delete the account I reauthenticate the user.

Here is my code :

```
let credentialFB = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        user!.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentialFB) { error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Unable to reauthenticate")
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                // User re-authenticated.
                user!.deleteWithCompletion { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        NSLog("Unable to delete account")
                        // An error happened.
                    } else {
                        //do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this is supposed to be simple but I can't make it work.

Do you have any idea where this could comes from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by Firebase.